# I'm trying to write an installer for a Windows print driver and I keep getting error 2 or 87 from GetLastError()

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-driver

I called `pnputil /a my.inf` via `CreateProcess()` and that was successful. I gave up on trying to use the Windows API.  I am then attempting to use `AddPrinterDriver()` to add the printer, but it keeps failing:

```
if (RunWindowsPnpUtil(thePrinterInfo))
{
    //std::vector<std::wstring> vecInstallPaths = GetInstalledDriverPaths();
    //std::vector<std::wstring> vecInstanceIDs = GetDeviceInstanceIDsUsingDriver(thePrinterInfo);
    wstring wsDriverName = thePrinterInfo.GetPrinterName(), wsInfPath = thePrinterInfo.GetINFPath();
    wstring wsDir = wsInfPath.substr(0, wsInfPath.find_last_of(L'\\')), wsINFName = wsInfPath.substr(wsInfPath.find_last_of(L'\\') + 1);
    DRIVER_INFO_4 driverInfo = { 0 };
    memset(&driverInfo, 0, sizeof(DRIVER_INFO_3));
    wstring wsConfigFile = thePrinterInfo.GetConfigFile(), wsDataFile = thePrinterInfo.GetDataFile();
    driverInfo.cVersion = thePrinterInfo.GetPrinterClassVersionInt(); // Specify the version of the structure
    driverInfo.pName = const_cast<wchar_t*>(wsDriverName.c_str()); // Driver name
    driverInfo.pEnvironment = NULL; // Use the current environment
    driverInfo.pDriverPath = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"UNIDRV.DLL"); // The path to the driver files (optional)
    driverInfo.pDataFile = const_cast<wchar_t*>(thePrinterInfo.GetGPDFile().c_str()); // NULL; // const_cast<wchar_t*>(wsInfPath.c_str()); // Path to the INF file
    driverInfo.pConfigFile = const_cast<wchar_t*>(wsConfigFile.empty() ? L"UNIDRVUI.DLL" : wsConfigFile.c_str());; // The path to the configuration file (optional)
    driverInfo.pHelpFile = const_cast<wchar_t*>(L"UNIDRV.HLP"); // The path to the help file (optional)
    driverInfo.pDependentFiles = NULL; // Array of dependent files (optional)
    driverInfo.pMonitorName = NULL; // Monitor name (optional)
    driverInfo.pDefaultDataType = NULL; // Default data type (optional)

    // Add the printer driver
    //DWORD level = driverInfo.cVersion;
    if (AddPrinterDriver(NULL, driverInfo.cVersion, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>(&driverInfo)) == 0) {
        // Failed to add printer driver
        DWORD dwErr = GetLastError();
        return false;
    }
```

For context, this is an XPS mini driver (`filter.dll`).

If you need more information, I'll be happy to provide it.  I'm desperate, Google, Reddit, and ChatGPT, are no help.

AddPrinterDriver returns FAILURE and dwErr == 2 or dwErr == 87, depending on whether driverInfo.pDataFile is NULL or points to a valid filename. Ultimately, my goal is to parse the inf, copy the files whether they need to go, and Add the Printer. I have some old Pascal code I'm using as a guide. I used ChatGPT to convert it to C++ and then I married it to my actualy code. It's literally just the AddPrinterDriver that is failing. Everything is working as expected

If someone knows of a better way to read an INF, prase it, copy the relevant files to the Driver Store, add the printer driver, and finally add the printer, let me know.  MSDN used to be wonderful, but like everything else, it's not wonderful.  And ChatGPT is literally spitting out nonsense that isn't real Windows API.

UPDATE:

```
HRESULT hResult = UploadPrinterDriverPackage(NULL, wsInfPath.c_str(), wsEnv.c_str(), UPDP_CHECK_DRIVERSTORE, NULL/*GetMainWnd()*/, wszDestInfPath, &cchDestInfPath);
if (hResult == S_OK)
{
    hResult = InstallPrinterDriverFromPackage(NULL, wszDestInfPath, wsDriverName.c_str(), wsEnv.c_str(), 0);
    if (hResult == S_OK)
    {
```

IS SUCCESSFUL!

However, a subsequent call to AddPrinterDriver is still failing FILE_NOT_FOUND (2)

basically, instead of if (RunWindowsPnpUtil(thePrinterInfo)), I am calling UploadPrinterDriverPackage and InstallPrinterDriverFromPackage.  And that worked.  Of course, the pnputil /a worked too, but this way return a destInfPath.  Oh, help!  I feel like I am so close, yet so far away still.

Comment: It keeps failing _how_ and _where_? Remember to [fully describe the problem]: what did you set out to do, what code did you write and _why did you write that specific code_, what steps do you take to compile and run it, at what point does that stop behaving how you expected it to, what error(s) did you get, and what debugging and (re)searching did you already do (and _talk about that_, don't just say  "I searched the web": what did you search for, what did you find, what did you then try, and what did that result in)

Comment: AddPrinterDriver returns FAILURE and dwErr == 2 or dwErr == 87, depending on whether driverInfo.pDataFile is NULL or points to a valid filename.  Ultimately, my goal is to parse the inf, copy the files whether they need to go, and Add the Printer.  I have some old Pascal code I'm using as a guide.  I used ChatGPT to convert it to C++ and then I married it to my actualy code.  It's literally just the AddPrinterDriver that is failing.  Everything is working as expected

Comment: I'm more worried about the FILE_NOT_FOUND (2) error, since the files exist.

Comment: On a side note: you are declaring `driverInfo` as a `DRIVER_INFO_4` but then zeroing it out with `memset` using `sizeof(DRIVER_INFO_3)`. You don't need that `memset` at all since you already zeroed it out with `{0}`.

Comment: Please remember that details go [in your post](/help/how-to-ask), not in comments. Hit the [edit] link and update your post to run people through the process, with all those details worked in.

Comment: Check [Preinstalling Driver Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/preinstalling-driver-packages)(SetupCopyOEMInf) whether it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You said in a comment:

> AddPrinterDriver returns FAILURE and dwErr == 2 or dwErr == 87, depending on whether driverInfo.pDataFile is NULL or points to a valid filename.

One problem I see is that on this line:

```cpp
driverInfo.pDataFile = const_cast<wchar_t*>(thePrinterInfo.GetGPDFile().c_str());
```

If `GetGPDFile()` returns a `wstring` by value rather than by reference, this will produce a *dangling pointer* causing **Undefined Behavior**. You should save the result of `GetGPDFile()` to a local variable first, like you do with your other strings, eg:

```cpp
wstring wsGPDFile = thePrinterInfo.GetGPDFile();
driverInfo.pDataFile = const_cast<wchar_t*>(wsGPDFile.c_str());
```

---

On a side note, if you are compiling for C++17 or later:

- `std::wstring` has a non-const `data()` method that you can use instead of `const_cast`, eg:

  ```cpp
  driverInfo.pDataFile = wsGPDFile.data();
  ```
- consider using `std::filesystem::path` instead of parsing file paths manually, eg:

  ```
  #include <filesystem>
  namespace fs = std::filesystem;

  fs::path fsInfPath = thePrinterInfo.GetINFPath();
  wstring wsDir = fsInfPath.parent_path();
  wstring wsINFName = fsInfPath.filename();
  ```

Comment: Remy, thanks for that.  I couldn't remember it off the top of my head.